# Simple conditional statement

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, conditional

%%[IF AccountNumber == "12345" THEN]%%
html
%%[ELSE]%%
html
%%[ENDIF]%%

Explodes when attempting to validate:

> Error 1: Script IF Statement Invalid
> An error occurred when
>   attempting to resolve a script expression. See inner exception for
>   detail.
>
> Script Expression: AccountNumber MemberID: 1234567 JobID: 0 An
>   unrecognized expression appears in a script block.
>
> Script Expression: AccountNumber MemberID: 1234567 JobID: 0
>   
> Invalid Content: 
> IF AccountNumber == "12345" THEN]%% !!plain
>   text stuff!! %%=WorkOrderNumber=%%. %%[

Not exactly helpful.

Checked data extension exists, is populated.

Comment: is this marketing cloud? you should tag it as such. thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation would be to set a variable for the Data Extension column or Personalization String using the [AttributeValue()](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#AttributeValue) function.  It handles missing objects better, which is likely your issue.

```
%%[

var @AccountNumber 
set @AccountNumber = AttributeValue("AccountNumber")

]%%

%%[IF @AccountNumber == "12345" THEN]%%

  account content

%%[ELSE]%%

  default content

%%[ENDIF]%%
```